# CSS transition div width from center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a little menu animation, nothing groundbreaking but just as an experiment. This is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
div.menu {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;

  div.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #444;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;

    &:nth-child(1) {
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
     top: 11px;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
     top: 11px;
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
     bottom: 0;
    }
  }

  &.active {

    div.bar {
      &:nth-child(1) {
        width: 0;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
     width: 0;
    }
    }
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
    menu.classList.toggle('active');
  });
```

And this is a pen of it in action:
https://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/eWJKKN

Currently, when the menu is active the top and bottom `div.bar` reduce their width to 0 to the left. I would like to adjust this so they reduce their width to the center. I have tried messing with margins for them but had no luck, if anyone could shed some light or suggest a different approach if needed that would be great.

Mike

Comment: try `transform-origin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin` to do this:

with respect to your dimensions it would be `12px` up and down(+ and -) as in the code below:

```
&.active {
  div.bar {
    &:nth-child(1) {
      transform-origin:12px 12px;
      transform: scale(0);
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
      transform-origin:12px -12px;
      transform: scale(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Check this out: [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/2xke5ghn/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the pseudo elements to split up the transform animation. 
[Demo (no script version)](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/oWbOQg)

**HTML** (note only three bars)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu" hidden>
<label for="toggle-menu" class="menu">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</label>
```

**SCSS**

```
//  two step transition    
//  as translate and rotation can't (yet) be animated individually 
//  we use the pseudo elements to split up the animation
// 
//  - bar elements will handle the vertical transform
//  - :after elements will handle rotation/scale

//  variables to control transition time and delay
$transition-time:  300ms;
$transition-delay: 300ms;

.menu {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
.bar {
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width:100%;

    //  Entering `hamburger` state 
    //  1) add a delay on bars to wait for the :after elements to rotate/scale back 
    //  2) the :after elements have no delay 
    transition: $transition-time $transition-delay; // 1

    &:after { 
        content:''; 
        display:table; 
        background: black; 
        position: inherit; width: inherit; height:inherit;
        transition: $transition-time; // 2
    }

    //  transform the bars into hamburger 
    &:nth-child(1){ transform: translateY(-8px); }
    &:nth-child(3){ transform: translateY(8px);}    
}

//    when toggle-menu checkbox is checked transform to `X`  
[id="toggle-menu"]:checked ~ .menu {
    .bar {
        //  Entering `X` state 
        //  1) to animate bars to the center we simply remove the transform
        //  2) as we are now animating backwards we switch the transition
        //     on the bars and their :after elements
        transform: none;  // 1  
        transition: $transition-time; // 2
        &:after { transition: $transition-time $transition-delay } // 2

        //  rotate the top and bottom :after elements
        &:nth-child(1):after{ transform: rotate(-45deg); }
        &:nth-child(3):after{ transform: rotate(45deg);}         

        //  hide the middle :after by scaling to zero
        //  (when all bars are at the center)
        &:nth-child(2):after{ transform: scale(0); }        
    }
}
```